# Tizen Studio: An error has occurred (java null pointer exception)

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app

I have just installed Tizen Studio 2.3.1. I do not have prior experience with this. I want to change my C/C++ build configuration for a project I downloaded from GitHub. However, whenever I click on Tizen Settings, I get an error that says:

```
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.  
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

[image]

So I checked the logs and it says "There is no available rootstrap for architecture".
I am not quite sure what it means so I am pasting it below:

```
    SESSION 2023-01-30 15:00:31.659 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=5.0 
java.version=1.8.0_242
java.vendor=Amazon.com Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

This is a continuation of log file C:\Users\humai\workspace\.metadata\.bak_4.log
Created Time: 2023-01-30 15:01:03.064

!ENTRY org.tizen.nativecommon.build.CommonConfigurationManager 4 0 2023-01-30 15:01:03.065
!MESSAGE [2023.01.30 15:01:03][ERROR] CommonConfigurationManager.java(436) - Failed to verify build target

!STACK 0
org.tizen.nativecommon.build.exception.SBIException: There is no avaiable rootstrap for architecture
    at org.tizen.nativecommon.build.CommonBuildTargetManager.getDefaultBuildTargetName(CommonBuildTargetManager.java:98)
    at org.tizen.nativecommon.build.CommonBuildTargetManager.getDefaultBuildTargetName(CommonBuildTargetManager.java:187)
    at org.tizen.nativecommon.build.CommonConfigurationManager.getDefaultBuildTargetName(CommonConfigurationManager.java:2835)
    at org.tizen.nativecommon.build.CommonConfigurationManager.verifyTarget(CommonConfigurationManager.java:429)
    at org.tizen.nativecommon.build.CommonBuildTargetManager.getBuildTargetName(CommonBuildTargetManager.java:277)
    at org.tizen.nativecommon.build.CommonConfigurationManager.getBuildTargetName(CommonConfigurationManager.java:2823)
    at org.tizen.nativecommon.build.CommonConfigurationManager.getRootstrapPath(CommonConfigurationManager.java:2851)
    at org.tizen.nativecore.build.NativeCoreConfigurationEnvVarSupplier.getEnvSysrootPath(NativeCoreConfigurationEnvVarSupplier.java:343)
    at org.tizen.nativecore.build.NativeCoreConfigurationEnvVarSupplier.getVariable(NativeCoreConfigurationEnvVarSupplier.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.envvar.ExternalExtensionEnvironmentSupplier.getVariable(ExternalExtensionEnvironmentSupplier.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.dataprovider.BuildEnvironmentContributor.getVariable(BuildEnvironmentContributor.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.envvar.BuildSystemEnvironmentSupplier.getVariable(BuildSystemEnvironmentSupplier.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.envvar.EnvironmentVariableManager.getVariable(EnvironmentVariableManager.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.envvar.EnvironmentVariableManager.getVariable(EnvironmentVariableManager.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.cdtvariables.EnvironmentVariableSupplier.getMacro(EnvironmentVariableSupplier.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.cdtvariables.CoreMacroSupplierBase.getVariable(CoreMacroSupplierBase.java:23)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.cdtvariables.SupplierBasedCdtVariableManager.getVariable(SupplierBasedCdtVariableManager.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.cdtvariables.SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.resolveMacro(SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.cdtvariables.SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.resolveMacro(SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.cdtvariables.SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.getResolvedMacro(SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.cdtvariables.SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.resolveToString(SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.cdtvariables.SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.resolveToString(SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.cdtvariables.CdtVariableResolver.resolveToString(CdtVariableResolver.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.cdtvariables.CdtVariableManager.resolveValue(CdtVariableManager.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.language.settings.providers.MBSLanguageSettingsProvider.getSettingEntries(MBSLanguageSettingsProvider.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.language.settings.providers.LanguageSettingsProvidersSerializer$LanguageSettingsWorkspaceProvider.getSettingEntries(LanguageSettingsProvidersSerializer.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.language.settings.providers.LanguageSettingsProvidersSerializer.getSettingEntriesPooled(LanguageSettingsProvidersSerializer.java:1421)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.language.settings.providers.LanguageSettingsProvidersSerializer.getSettingEntriesUpResourceTree(LanguageSettingsProvidersSerializer.java:1449)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.language.settings.providers.LanguageSettingsProvidersSerializer.getSettingEntriesByKind(LanguageSettingsProvidersSerializer.java:1508)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.language.settings.providers.LanguageSettingsProvidersSerializer.getLocalSettingEntriesByKind(LanguageSettingsProvidersSerializer.java:1590)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.language.settings.providers.LanguageSettingsScannerInfoProvider.getScannerInformation(LanguageSettingsScannerInfoProvider.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.language.settings.providers.LanguageSettingsScannerInfoProvider.getScannerInformation(LanguageSettingsScannerInfoProvider.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.TranslationUnit.getScannerInfo(TranslationUnit.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.TranslationUnit.getAST(TranslationUnit.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.TranslationUnit.getAST(TranslationUnit.java:838)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.ASTCache$1.run(ASTCache.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.ASTCache.createAST(ASTCache.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.ASTCache.getAST(ASTCache.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.ASTCache.acquireSharedAST(ASTCache.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.ASTCache.runOnAST(ASTCache.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.ui.editor.ASTProvider.runOnAST(ASTProvider.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.SelectionListenerWithASTManager$PartListenerGroup.calculateASTandInform(SelectionListenerWithASTManager.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.SelectionListenerWithASTManager$PartListenerGroup$1.run(SelectionListenerWithASTManager.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)

!ENTRY org.tizen.nativecommon.build.CommonConfigurationManager 4 0 2023-01-30 15:01:03.067
!MESSAGE [2023.01.30 15:01:03][ERROR] CommonConfigurationManager.java(436) - Failed to verify build target

!STACK 0
org.tizen.nativecommon.build.exception.SBIException: There is no avaiable rootstrap for architecture
    at org.tizen.nativecommon.build.CommonBuildTargetManager.getDefaultBuildTargetName(CommonBuildTargetManager.java:98)
    at org.tizen.nativecommon.build.CommonBuildTargetManager.getDefaultBuildTargetName(CommonBuildTargetManager.java:187)
    at org.tizen.nativecommon.build.CommonConfigurationManager.getDefaultBuildTargetName(CommonConfigurationManager.java:2835)
    at org.tizen.nativecommon.build.CommonConfigurationManager.verifyTarget(CommonConfigurationManager.java:429)
    at org.tizen.nativecommon.build.CommonBuildTargetManager.getBuildTargetName(CommonBuildTargetManager.java:277)
    at org.tizen.nativecommon.build.CommonConfigurationManager.getBuildTargetName(CommonConfigurationManager.java:2823)
    at org.tizen.nativecore.build.NativeCoreProjectDependentBuilder.getTargetID(NativeCoreProjectDependentBuilder.java:106)
    at org.tizen.nativecore.build.NativeCoreConfigurationManager.getTargetIdFromProject(NativeCoreConfigurationManager.java:1102)
    at org.tizen.nativecore.build.NativeCoreConfigurationEnvVarSupplier.getVariable(NativeCoreConfigurationEnvVarSupplier.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.envvar.ExternalExtensionEnvironmentSupplier.getVariable(ExternalExtensionEnvironmentSupplier.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.dataprovider.BuildEnvironmentContributor.getVariable(BuildEnvironmentContributor.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.envvar.BuildSystemEnvironmentSupplier.getVariable(BuildSystemEnvironmentSupplier.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.envvar.EnvironmentVariableManager.getVariable(EnvironmentVariableManager.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.envvar.EnvironmentVariableManager.getVariable(EnvironmentVariableManager.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.cdtvariables.EnvironmentVariableSupplier.getMacro(EnvironmentVariableSupplier.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.cdtvariables.CoreMacroSupplierBase.getVariable(CoreMacroSupplierBase.java:23)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.cdtvariables.SupplierBasedCdtVariableManager.getVariable(SupplierBasedCdtVariableManager.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.cdtvariables.SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.resolveMacro(SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.cdtvariables.SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.resolveMacro(SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.cdtvariables.SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.getResolvedMacro(SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.cdtvariables.SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.resolveToString(SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.cdtvariables.SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.resolveToString(SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.cdtvariables.CdtVariableResolver.resolveToString(CdtVariableResolver.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.cdtvariables.CdtVariableManager.resolveValue(CdtVariableManager.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.language.settings.providers.MBSLanguageSettingsProvider.getSettingEntries(MBSLanguageSettingsProvider.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.language.settings.providers.LanguageSettingsProvidersSerializer$LanguageSettingsWorkspaceProvider.getSettingEntries(LanguageSettingsProvidersSerializer.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.language.settings.providers.LanguageSettingsProvidersSerializer.getSettingEntriesPooled(LanguageSettingsProvidersSerializer.java:1421)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.language.settings.providers.LanguageSettingsProvidersSerializer.getSettingEntriesUpResourceTree(LanguageSettingsProvidersSerializer.java:1449)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.language.settings.providers.LanguageSettingsProvidersSerializer.getSettingEntriesByKind(LanguageSettingsProvidersSerializer.java:1508)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.language.settings.providers.LanguageSettingsProvidersSerializer.getSettingEntriesByKind(LanguageSettingsProvidersSerializer.java:1550)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.language.settings.providers.LanguageSettingsScannerInfoProvider.getScannerInformation(LanguageSettingsScannerInfoProvider.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.language.settings.providers.LanguageSettingsScannerInfoProvider.getScannerInformation(LanguageSettingsScannerInfoProvider.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.TranslationUnit.getScannerInfo(TranslationUnit.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.TranslationUnit.getAST(TranslationUnit.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.TranslationUnit.getAST(TranslationUnit.java:838)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.ASTCache$1.run(ASTCache.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.ASTCache.createAST(ASTCache.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.ASTCache.getAST(ASTCache.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.ASTCache.acquireSharedAST(ASTCache.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.ASTCache.runOnAST(ASTCache.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.ui.editor.ASTProvider.runOnAST(ASTProvider.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.SelectionListenerWithASTManager$PartListenerGroup.calculateASTandInform(SelectionListenerWithASTManager.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.SelectionListenerWithASTManager$PartListenerGroup$1.run(SelectionListenerWithASTManager.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)

!ENTRY org.tizen.nativecommon.build.CommonConfigurationManager 4 0 2023-01-30 15:01:03.069
!MESSAGE [2023.01.30 15:01:03][ERROR] CommonConfigurationManager.java(436) - Failed to verify build target

!STACK 0
org.tizen.nativecommon.build.exception.SBIException: There is no avaiable rootstrap for architecture
    at org.tizen.nativecommon.build.CommonBuildTargetManager.getDefaultBuildTargetName(CommonBuildTargetManager.java:98)
    at org.tizen.nativecommon.build.CommonBuildTargetManager.getDefaultBuildTargetName(CommonBuildTargetManager.java:187)
    at org.tizen.nativecommon.build.CommonConfigurationManager.getDefaultBuildTargetName(CommonConfigurationManager.java:2835)
    at org.tizen.nativecommon.build.CommonConfigurationManager.verifyTarget(CommonConfigurationManager.java:429)
    at org.tizen.nativecommon.build.CommonBuildTargetManager.getBuildTargetName(CommonBuildTargetManager.java:277)
    at org.tizen.nativecommon.build.CommonConfigurationManager.getBuildTargetName(CommonConfigurationManager.java:2823)
    at org.tizen.nativecommon.build.CommonConfigurationManager.getRootstrapPath(CommonConfigurationManager.java:2851)
    at org.tizen.nativecore.build.NativeCoreConfigurationEnvVarSupplier.getEnvSysrootPath(NativeCoreConfigurationEnvVarSupplier.java:343)
    at org.tizen.nativecore.build.NativeCoreConfigurationEnvVarSupplier.getVariable(NativeCoreConfigurationEnvVarSupplier.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.envvar.ExternalExtensionEnvironmentSupplier.getVariable(ExternalExtensionEnvironmentSupplier.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.dataprovider.BuildEnvironmentContributor.getVariable(BuildEnvironmentContributor.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.envvar.BuildSystemEnvironmentSupplier.getVariable(BuildSystemEnvironmentSupplier.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.envvar.EnvironmentVariableManager.getVariable(EnvironmentVariableManager.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.envvar.EnvironmentVariableManager.getVariable(EnvironmentVariableManager.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.cdtvariables.EnvironmentVariableSupplier.getMacro(EnvironmentVariableSupplier.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.cdtvariables.CoreMacroSupplierBase.getVariable(CoreMacroSupplierBase.java:23)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.cdtvariables.SupplierBasedCdtVariableManager.getVariable(SupplierBasedCdtVariableManager.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.cdtvariables.SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.resolveMacro(SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.cdtvariables.SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.resolveMacro(SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.cdtvariables.SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.getResolvedMacro(SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.cdtvariables.SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.resolveToString(SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.cdtvariables.SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.resolveToString(SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.cdtvariables.CdtVariableResolver.resolveToString(CdtVariableResolver.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.cdtvariables.CdtVariableManager.resolveValue(CdtVariableManager.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.language.settings.providers.MBSLanguageSettingsProvider.getSettingEntries(MBSLanguageSettingsProvider.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.language.settings.providers.LanguageSettingsProvidersSerializer$LanguageSettingsWorkspaceProvider.getSettingEntries(LanguageSettingsProvidersSerializer.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.language.settings.providers.LanguageSettingsProvidersSerializer.getSettingEntriesPooled(LanguageSettingsProvidersSerializer.java:1421)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.language.settings.providers.LanguageSettingsProvidersSerializer.getSettingEntriesUpResourceTree(LanguageSettingsProvidersSerializer.java:1449)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.language.settings.providers.LanguageSettingsProvidersSerializer.getSettingEntriesByKind(LanguageSettingsProvidersSerializer.java:1508)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.language.settings.providers.LanguageSettingsProvidersSerializer.getSettingEntriesByKind(LanguageSettingsProvidersSerializer.java:1550)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.language.settings.providers.LanguageSettingsScannerInfoProvider.getScannerInformation(LanguageSettingsScannerInfoProvider.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.language.settings.providers.LanguageSettingsScannerInfoProvider.getScannerInformation(LanguageSettingsScannerInfoProvider.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.TranslationUnit.getScannerInfo(TranslationUnit.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.TranslationUnit.getAST(TranslationUnit.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.TranslationUnit.getAST(TranslationUnit.java:838)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.ASTCache$1.run(ASTCache.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.ASTCache.createAST(ASTCache.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.ASTCache.getAST(ASTCache.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.ASTCache.acquireSharedAST(ASTCache.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.ASTCache.runOnAST(ASTCache.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.ui.editor.ASTProvider.runOnAST(ASTProvider.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.SelectionListenerWithASTManager$PartListenerGroup.calculateASTandInform(SelectionListenerWithASTManager.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.SelectionListenerWithASTManager$PartListenerGroup$1.run(SelectionListenerWithASTManager.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for asking your question here.
Every year, we release a new version.
TizenStudio 5.0 is the latest version and you can download it from https://developer.tizen.org/
Guide: https://docs.tizen.org/application/tizen-studio/
Could you follow the above URL to install a new TizenStudio?
It's a too old version and it seems to be difficult to check your situation.

If you have any more things, please update again.
Thanks